# Variations in Spelling Names, especially on Matzevot

Tags: names

With all my reading of inscriptions on matzevot, especially in Slovakia, I come across issues I cannot resolve.

Take the name of Yehuda (יהודה). Anyone with some knowledge of the Torah and shevatim knows how it should be spelled.  That it also has within it shem H-shem is readily discernible.  So I wonder why I have seen it written variously as יהודא, with an aleph at the end, or Yuda (יודא, יודה).  Were they being so cautious as to not inscribe shem H-shem?  If this is a Yiddish form of the name, why use this form rather than the real Hebrew spelling?

Would they even have written it in one of these ways on a ketuba or get?

Any suggestions for this practice?

Thanks in advance.

To all who responded, thanks for all your observations.

I'd like to add, that I may still have a puzzle though:  I might expect that if they had some additional wording in Aramaic on a matzeva, that then they might have been consistent with Yehuda with an aleph.  It will take some time to review those instances.

In the thousands of Ashkenazi matzevot I have looked at so far, it was very rare indeed to find an inscription in Yiddish.  So maybe as some have indicated it is just a minhag (custom) and I just won't worry about it too much.

Comment: יהודא and יודא are Aramaic. By the way, take a look at the title page to a popular Yiddish Chumash: http://seforimsets.com/image/data/Chumash%20Beis%20Yehudah_0001%20copy.jpg

Comment: https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/90742/can-you-pronounce-yehuda-the-way-it-is-spelled/90756#90756

Comment: You will see a similar changing of vowels in the words ייִדיש (Jewish) and ייִדישקייט (Jewishness). It originates from  יהודה or, rather, יהודי. The letter *heh* has been dropped.

Comment: Why do you think they should prefer "the real Hebrew spelling" to the real Yiddish spelling? Especially if they lived in Yiddish speaking countries.

Comment: @DanF The more "correct" spelling of the word _Yiddish_ is either אידיש or יודיש; the spelling "ייִדיש" is a later invention.

Comment: Thanks @ezra. I was wondering about the use of the *aleph* that I had been seeing in some local papers.

Comment: Off-topic as a question about spelling of Hebrew Jewish names rather than Judaism?

Comment: [possibly related](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/90742)

Answer (score 1):

Many people have the custom of not writing the name יהודה  with the four letters of the Shem H-Shem readily discernible (as you have noted) for fear of it not being treated with due respect.

This is not halacha but custom.

Comment: Source? [15 char]